# Pandas - Extracting value from a pandas column that has data as a dict

Tags: pandas

I am trying to extract a details from a pandas column that is a dict as shown below:

```
id, details
101, {'title': '',
      'phone': '',
      'skype': '',
      'real_name': 'Kevin'}
102, {'title': '',
      'phone': '',
      'skype': '',
      'real_name': 'Scott'}
```

Expected output:

Trying to extract name real_name value within the dict column

```
id, details
101, Kevin
102, Scott
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str` accessor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [101, 102],
    'details': [{'title': '',
                 'phone': '',
                 'skype': '',
                 'real_name': 'Kevin'},
                {'title': '',
                 'phone': '',
                 'skype': '',
                 'real_name': 'Scott'}]
})

df['details'] = df['details'].str['real_name']

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
    id details
0  101   Kevin
1  102   Scott
```

Comment: thank you did not know I could extract this using the `str` method